# SQL Server -- Update value if value is equal to '2017'

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update all value in the table if its value is equal to '2017'.

I have about 60000 records that have been recorded over the years and I need to update all 2017 records to 2018

My query currently:

```
SELECT  
    [sales], [user],
    [Month], [Year],
    [sale]
FROM 
    [System].[dbo].[sales]
WHERE
    [Year] = '2017'
```

which returns all the 2017 sales. How do I update all 2017 to 2018?

Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: Seems like an odd idea. Why change year for last years sales?

Comment: Just for testing purpose

Comment: This is a simple update query. Five seconds of research would have gotten you the answer.

Comment: You have both sale and sales columns??? Sheesh take about ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

if [Year] is integer, you don't need to enclosed it in single quote

```
UPDATE [System].[dbo].[sales]
SET [Year] = 2018
WHERE [Year] = 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

There's this ..

```
UPDATE [System].[dbo].[sales]
SET [Year] = '2018'
WHERE [Year] = '2017'
```

Comment: Thank you MiguelH!